# Write a file only downloads 1k

Tags: python, file-io, urllib

Can anyone tell me why it only downloads 1k bytes of the image (same problem when I use `urlretrieve()`)? The size of image is much bigger than that.

```
f = open('00000001.gif','wb')
f.write(urllib.urlopen('http://gifs.gifbin.com/082013/tn_1378920172_decapitated_snake_bites_itself.gif').read())
f.close()
```

Comment: Your code works for me perfectly. It downloads the image (8KB) into current directory and names it `00000001.gif`

Comment: maybe i use eclipse? it worked fine a few days ago, suddenly it went wrong

Comment: 8 kb it not the total size of the image, the image is larger than that , you can't open it neither

Comment: @hln, 8kb is the size of the data sent by the server and is a complete image. If you are receiving less than that you probably have an intervening proxy server with a corrupted cache. Do you get the whole 8k or only part of it when you open the image in a web browser?

Comment: the image i want to dwonload is 196kb, i got 8kb too, but it is still not a full size of the picture

Comment: Maybe the image you want to download is 196kb but the image you are downloading is 8kb.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, i got a wrong link

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify either your network or the URL you are trying to retrieve; Python will read from the result socket until EOF is reached so if you got less data than expected, you either were sent an incomplete response, the network cut the response short (proxy server, firewall, what-have-you), or your assumption about what the server sends for that URL is wrong.

You also want to use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to do the reading for you:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

im = urllib.urlopen('http://gifs.gifbin.com/082013/tn_1378920172_decapitated_snake_bites_itself.gif')
with open('00000001.gif', 'wb') as out:
    copyfileobj(im, out)
```

This will not only handle reading the data in chunks, but will avoid filling memory with large blobs of binary data to boot. The `with` statement handles closing the file object for you.

Comment: it does the same, only a few kilo bytes

Comment: Then you have something else in your network cutting of the response; the problem lies *outside* of Python.

Comment: what would that be? i have run it on my pc and mac, it gav the same result

Comment: A proxy on your network perhaps? I certainly cannot reproduce your problem here.

Comment: have you tried the code, and try to open the downloaded image, it is not full size

Comment: The link you provided is only 8kb small. Check your URL.

Comment: Martijn, are you sure the first sentence of your answer applies to the `urllib` objects as well? I always thought that they are compensating for the possibility that a `recv()` returns fewer bytes than requested...

Comment: I just had a look: it all breaks down to `socket._fileobject` whose `.read()` indeed calls `.recv()` repeatedly until the request is fulfilled.

Comment: @glglgl: indeed; I'll remove that; it defaults to an automatic read-until-EOF.

Answer (score -1):

Just change read() to read(-1).

Comment: Actually, for sockets the default is `-1`; something else is wrong for the OP, I suspect.